# How to rotate iPhone image 90 degrees after uploading file

Tags: php, android, mysql, iphone, ionic-framework

I'm trying to upload an image and display the image on my app. I'm using Javascript (angularjs) and I'm using PHP for the image rotation. When I upload an image using an android device the image is perfectly fine but when using an iPhone the image is always turned 90 degrees. I searched for a solution for some time now and I can't find one. Right now I'm trying to do an image rotation using PHP on my server and it still works fine with android. I originally pulled exif orientation data from the picture and tried to rotate it depending on what value was returned.

Here is an example of the code I used.

```
require '../db.php';
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) { 
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    $exif = exif_read_data($source_url);

    if($image && $exif && isset($exif['Orientation'])){
        $ort = $exif['Orientation'];
        echo 'exif data available';
        if($ort == 6 || $ort == 5){
            $image = imagerotate($image, 270, null);
        }
        if($ort == 3 || $ort == 4){
            $image = imagerotate($image, 180, null);
        }
        if($ort == 8 || $ort == 7){
            $image = imagerotate($image, 90, null);
        }
        if($ort == 5 || $ort == 4 || $ort == 7){
            imageflip($image, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
        }
    }
    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
}
$imgname = $_FILES["file"]['name'];
$image = $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'];
$userid = $_POST["userid"];
$postid = $_POST["postid"];
compress_image($image, "../uploads/".$imgname, 50);
$query="insert into photos (user_id,post_id,photoname) values ($userid,$postid,'$imgname')";
$result =  mysqli_query($conn,$query);
mysqli_close($conn);
echo 'success';
```

Since this didn't work for iPhone (the picture still stayed sideways) I then wanted to check if at least the rotation worked.

So I ended up using this PHP code

```
require '../db.php';
function compress_image($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {  
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url);
    $image = imagerotate($image, 270, null);
    imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
}
$imgname = $_FILES["file"]['name'];
$image = $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'];
$userid = $_POST["userid"];
$postid = $_POST["postid"];
compress_image($image, "../uploads/".$imgname, 50);
$query="insert into photos (user_id,post_id,photoname) values ($userid,$postid,'$imgname')";
$result =  mysqli_query($conn,$query);
mysqli_close($conn);
echo 'success';
```

By using this piece of code I was certain that the picture would at least rotate 270 degrees but the picture didn't show up at all but the weird thing is that it did rotate when I uploaded the image using my android device. It's just iPhone that is having the problem. If anyone has any suggestions as to how I could fix this problem I would appreciate it. Thanks.